# Extracting text :after an element with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I would like to extract the text `:after` the `<strong>` element.

```
 <li data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title=""><strong>06:25</strong> &nbsp;vP</li>
```

I've tried the following

```
 medmar_live_departures_table = list(soup.select('li.tratta'))
 for li in medmar_live_departures_table:     
    info = li.text
```

but I'm getting both texts. I could use re to split the string but I was wondering if there was a more efficient and straightforward way of doing it.

```
Output
16:40  vP

Desired output
vP
```

Comment: There is no `next_li` and also no `li` with class name `"tratta"`. Update your question

Comment: I've fixed it. My code is obviously more complicated but wanted to make the question easier to digest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get *last text child node of each `li`* as below:

```
medmar_live_departures_table = soup.select('li.tratta')
for li in medmar_live_departures_table :      
    info = [text for text in li.stripped_strings][-1]
    print(info)
```